# Airflow DockerOperator - Run a script in a running docker container

Tags: docker, airflow

My question is quite simple I guess.

I would like to use the **DockerOperator** to run a python script inside of a container, but I do not want to pull or run the container because my target container is already alive (already started). So, what I am expecting is just to run the python script using the command parameter (**command="python my_python_script.py"**)

```
with DAG('mydag',default_args=args,schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:

    task_1=DockerOperator(
        task_id='run_task1', 
        image='ABCDFG',
        container_name="EFGHIJKL",
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=False,
        user="root",
        working_dir="/mydirt",
        command="python my_python_script.py",
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock"
        )
```

I already tried different approaches to do this, but I could not achieve the expected result so far.
Does anyone has an idea in how to proceed in this case? I started thinking this is not possible.